# Ambiguity between method/field

Tags: c#

Is there any way besides renaming the field to assign it a value if its name is the same as a method?

As of writing this I was just thinking maybe reflection can be used.

Reflection works, but is there a better/different way of doing this?

```
FieldInfo fi = typeof(TheClass).GetField("TheClash");
fi.SetValue(TheClassObj, TheFieldValue);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code of the class having the same name for a method and field? As mentioned in an answer: this should not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look closer at [BindingsFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), which are optional arguments to Type.GetField(). There is one for GetField and one for GetProperty. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

How does it have the same name? That shouldnt (AFAIK) be commonly possible. If the problem is with a base-class, maybe:

```
base.fieldName = value;
```

If you mean method vs *variable*, then:

```
this.MethodName();
```

Other than that, the only way I see a problem is it you have "foo" and "Foo", and are calling from a case-insensitive language like VB.

Answer (score 1):

Why not cast TheClassObj to type TheClass and access it's property that way?

```
((TheClass)TheClassObj).TheField = "blah";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, reflection is the way to access fields or methode by their name. But why do you want to do this?

You can do:

```
public int Test{get;set;}
```

The compiler will then generate the variable under the hood for you.